# not able to execute the delete function for binary seach tree in pytho.Please suggest the required edit

Tags: python, binary-search-tree, delete-operator

please suggest some edit in the delete function for the binary tree in python.I am not able to delete any element with this part of code.

```
def min_value_node(self,cur_node):
        current=cur_node
        while(current.left is not None):
            current=current.left
        return current
def delete(self,data):
        if self.root==None:
            return False
        else:
            return self._delete(data,self.root)
def _delete(self,data,cur_node):
       if data>cur_node.data:
           self. _delete(data,cur_node.right)
       elif data>cur_node.data:
           self. _delete(data,cur_node.right)

       else:
           if data==cur_node.data:
               if cur_node.left is not None and cur_node.right is not None:
                   cur_node.data==self.min_value_node(cur_node.right)
           else: 
               if cur_node.left == None:  
                   cur_node = node.right
               elif cur_node.right == None:
                   cur_node = node.left
```

Comment: What happens when you try deleting some element?

Comment: It's not getting executed and I am not sure whether the part of the code in which a node has both the children is correct or not? 
as I am not sure how to delete the last children node in this part. 
Can you suggest an edit?